# Convert list of dictionaries to dataframe with one column for keys and one for values

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose I have the following list:

`list1 = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]`

Which I want to convert it to a panda dataframe that have two columns: one for the keys, and one for the values.

```
    keys    values
0    'a'      1
1    'b'      2
2    'c'      3
```

To do so, I have tried to use `pd.DataFrame(list1)` and also `pd.DataFrame.from_records(list1)`, but, in both cases, I get a dataframe like:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Is there any way to specify what I want? By doing research I could only find the way I am describing above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with flattening for list of tuples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, j) for a in list1 for i, j in a.items()], 
                   columns=['keys','values'])
print (df)
  keys  values
0    a       1
1    b       2
2    c       3
```

**Detail**:

```
print ([(i, j) for a in list1 for i, j in a.items()])

[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your keys across dictionaries are unique, you can create a single dictionary and feed to [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). This can be facilitated by [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

list1 = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ChainMap(*list1), orient='index').reset_index()

df.columns = ['key', 'value']

print(df)

  key  value
0   a      1
1   b      2
2   c      3
```

Alternatively, you can feed directly to `pd.DataFrame` constructor via a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(ChainMap(*list1).items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

While @jezrael answered perfectly to my question, I would like to point out that if you convert each dictionary (`{'a':1}`) to a list (`['a',1]`) you will simply need to use `pd.DataFrame(list1)`, getting the desired result.